# Key value pair params handling in Backbone.js Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parameters, query-string

I want to pass key value pairs as params to Backbone routes and want it to be deserialized to a javascript object before the mapped function is called.

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "dashboard?:params" : "show_dashboard"
  },
  show_dashboard: function(params){
     console.log(params); 
  }
});
```

When I go to "http://...#dashboard?key1=val1&key2=val2", then {key1: "val1", key2: "val2"} should be printed on the console.

Am currently using jQuery BBQ's $.deparam method inside each mapped function to get at the deserialized object. It would be nice if I can extend Router and define it just once so params is accessible inside all mapped functions as an object. What would be a clean way to do this? And are there some pitfalls in this??

Much thanks,

mano

Comment: I'd be careful with this.  You are generating a URI that might confuse your browser.  # and ? are considered reserved in the URI specification and ? is expected before #.  It might not be a problem, but this feels like it might cause unintended consequences in different browsers.  http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html

Comment: @BrianGenisio Thanks for the info. It works now but as you say it might stop working on a later date when the browsers start complying with the std :-) Will try an alternate approach.

Comment: @BrianGenisio I guess you are suggesting I replace the # with a / and take advantage of the HTML5 pushState. I read somewhere that mobile safari has problems with that!

Comment: Now am using '=' as the delimiter in the fragment instead of '?'. So, now  I use "http://...#dashboard=key1=val1&key2=val2" and remove the first '=' before deserializing it. Again, how to do it just once for all route functions? Thanks.

Comment: I was just suggesting that you do this: http://...#dashboard/key1=val1&key2=val2

Answer (score 10):

You should redefine `_extractParameters` function in `Backbone.Router`. Then all router functions will be invoked with the first parameter being `params` object.

```
// Backbone Router with a custom parameter extractor
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'dashboard/:country/:city/?:params': 'whereAmIActually',
        'dashboard/?:params': 'whereAmI'
    },
    whereAmIActually: function(params, country, city){
        console.log('whereAmIActually');
        console.log(arguments);
    },
    whereAmI: function(params){
        console.log('whereAmI');
        console.log(arguments);
    },
    _extractParameters: function(route, fragment) {
        var result = route.exec(fragment).slice(1);
        result.unshift(deparam(result[result.length-1]));
        return result.slice(0,-1);
    }
});

// simplified $.deparam analog
var deparam = function(paramString){
    var result = {};
    if( ! paramString){
        return result;
    }
    $.each(paramString.split('&'), function(index, value){
        if(value){
            var param = value.split('=');
            result[param[0]] = param[1];
        }
    });
    return result;
};

var router = new Router;
Backbone.history.start();

// this call assumes that the url has been changed
Backbone.history.loadUrl('dashboard/?planet=earth&system=solar');
Backbone.history.loadUrl('dashboard/usa/la/?planet=earth&system=solar');
```

The working demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/avrelian/h5wL2/).